# find more than 20 users mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

i have more than 20 users on my database and i am trying to display them on my page but it is only giving me 20 user

I am using scale grid as my cloud database and i tried using DBQuery.shellBatchSize = 300 on scale grids console but it doesn't work i also tried typing "it" but it says "Error:  it is not defined".

```
Users.find({},function(err,data){
  if(err){
      res.send(err)
  }
  if(data){
      res.send(data)
  }
})
```

only sends 20 users

```
 Product.find({},function(err,data){
  if(err){
      res.send(err)
  }
  if(data){
      res.send(data)
  }
  }).limit(200)
```

still prints out 20 users

Answer (score 0):

You need to set shellBatchSize in ~/.mongorc.js, but this should give you all the results regardless:

```
Users.find().toArray(function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err)
    }
    if (data) {
        res.send(data)
    }
})
```

Comment: it says "TypeError: Users.find(...).toArray is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with the cursor, which by default outputs 20 matches.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/#read-operations-cursors

You need to iterate over the cursor, to get other entries, similar to this one:

```
var myCursor = db.users.find( { type: 2 } );

while (myCursor.hasNext()) {
   print(tojson(myCursor.next()));
}
```